# Flutter : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile-development

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM A715F in debug mode...Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=trueException in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: DESKTOP-O8L0ETS 9204at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:526)at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:524)at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:523)at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:564)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:212)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1208)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1Exited (sigterm)
```

I am a student.
I am trying to run this app created by flutter but I get this error. I disabled all Java options yesterday thinking that was the problem
I am running on flutter version 2.10.3, dart version 2.16.1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it needs to download some resources. Try running your project while having an internet connection(it may take multiple running if the network is slow).

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading gradle version and the run "flutter clean" command in terminal and then try to build the project.